# Sign library before running Junit Android

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing

I'm developing unit test using `JUnit 4` on Android studio, but I need to sign the **library** before running tests to each function of the library to be accepted on my device. I'm trying the following:

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxx'
            storePassword 'xxxxxx'
            storeFile file('cert/platform.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    testBuildType "debug"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.111"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-fexceptions"
            }
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "api"
    productFlavors {
        minApi17 {
            dimension "api"
            ndk.with {
                moduleName = 'FAL'
                abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation files('libs/zxing-2.3.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

I'm using this portion of code, but the application don't work in device (Certification error). What is the proper way to sign the application before running the test?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Build -> Generate Signed APK -> Create new... -> add password, some credentials needed and click Next -> choose build type and flavors, check Signature Versions (check here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2) but tl;dr -> choose V2.

This way you will generate dummy certificate which will sign your builds. Your gradle file will update automatically. If not than add:

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'KEY'
        keyPassword 'PASSWORD'
        storeFile file('../cert/fileName.jks')
        storePassword 'STORE_PASSWORD'
    }
```

to your gradle file.

It's good practice to store generated cert inside your project repo.

Comment: I forgot of explain that I'm developing a library and the written tests is about of each function of this library. This solution give by you work for applications right? I updated my question.

Comment: I don't know how your code looks like. But Espresso tests are run by orchestrator, and the file send to device is acctually an .apk so this solution should work. But I didn't test it